# How to find the whole word in kotlin using regex

Tags: regex, kotlin

I want to find the whole word in string. But I don't know how to find the all word in kotlin. My finding word is [non alpha]cba[non alpha].  My example code is bellows.

```
val testLink3 = """cba@cba cba"""
val word = "cba"
val matcher = "\\b[^a-zA-Z]*(?i)$word[^a-zA-Z]*\\b".toRegex()
val ret = matcher.find(testLink3)?.groupValues
```

But output of my source code is "cba"
My expected value is string array such as "{cba, cba, cba}".
How to find this value in kotlin language.

Comment: Try something like: `(?i)\\b(?=([^a-z]*cba[^a-z]*))` and extract the capture group 1. If you don't want whitespaces in the results, add `\\s` to the negated character classes.

Comment: It is not worked... sorry, your code returned cba@

Comment: The main problem is that your expected matches overlap in a specific way. What will be the expected result if your string is `cba@@@cba cba`? I could "work around" to `val matcher = "(?i)(?=(\\b[^A-Z]*$word[^a-zA-Z]*\\b))".toRegex()` and `val ret = matcher.findAll(testLink3).map{it.groupValues[1].trim()}.toList().distinct()`. But it might extract more than you expect.

Comment: I want to count of "cba" word and alpha insensitive. So, My expected value is string array such as [cba, Cba, cBa]

Comment: Something like http://rextester.com/COSI60518 ?

Comment: Ok, but your answer not include [^a-zA-Z]. I want to not include alpha front or back. So, I used [^a-zA-Z]?($i)$word [^a-zA-Z]?. "cbacba" is not matched my expected result.

Comment: Please add the actual *precise* rules to the question. Add samples and explain the expected results. Then, add a comment with `@`+username in it to notify of feedback.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It is very simple rules. When searching for a search term, ignore case is ignored.
Words are separated by all other characters except alphabets. For example, when the search term is cba, the number of words in cbabcbabcba is zero.

Comment: Correct, so `"(?i)\\b$word\\b".toRegex().findAll(testLink3).map{it.value}.toList()` should work

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thank you, I'm solved this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use

```
val testLink3 = """cBa@Cba cbA123"""
val word = "cba"
val matcher = "(?i)(?<!\\p{L})$word(?!\\p{L})".toRegex()
println(matcher.findAll(testLink3).map{it.value}.toList() )
println(matcher.findAll(testLink3).count() )
// => [cBa, Cba, cbA]
// => 3
```

See the [online Kotlin demo](http://rextester.com/KOSVQ49497).

To obtain the list of matches, you need to run the `findAll` method on the regex object, map the results to values and cast to list:

```
.findAll(testLink3).map{it.value}.toList()
```

To count the matches, you may use

```
matcher.findAll(testLink3).count()
```

**Regex demo**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `(?<!\\p{L})` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is a letter
- `$word` - your `word` variable value
- `(?!\\p{L})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is a letter.

Comment: I'm so sorry, but, your code is invalid answer. For example if source code is             
  val testLink3 = """cba@cba cba123"""   your code returned 2 object. but "cba123" also word. Also your answer is not correct.

Comment: @dongwooktaehyung If you are searching for a whole word, you need `\bword\b`. If you need to match any word containing `word`, you need `\b\w*word\w*\b`. Please make sure you know what you need, then precise the question.

Comment: @dongwooktaehyung So, what do you need to match? Words *containing* your `word` value?

Comment: I said clearly on top : Words are separated by all other characters except alphabets

Comment: It is also three words in the following cases.  """Cba@cBa cbA123""".   But your code is returned 2 words.   [Cba, cBa].